# Github actions notifications to slack of all repos

Tags: github-actions

Can any one help me how to integrate github actions with slack.
My Exact point is for every push,pull on any repo in my github the notification should be popup in slack

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in just receiving notifications from Slack on push/pull events (and others), there are first-class Slack applications that do it. For example, check out [this one](https://slack.github.com/).

If you are looking for a more customizable solution, where you can formulate the specific message you want to send when very specific conditions are met *within your Github actions*, check out [Slack incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks). They allow you to send an arbitrary message to slack with a simple HTTP POST request, using something as low key as `curl`.

If you are looking for a systematic solution rather than solving this problem for yourself in a one-off way, [there are more considerations](https://fusebit.io/so/blog/bots-hooks-extensions/).